# SQL Server query to select records for a specific foreign key/month combination, or the master record if one does not exist for that day

Tags: sql-server

I need to run a query to select all meals offered on a school menu for a month.  However, if a meal has not yet been entered for any of the days, I need to pull in the master menu's meal for that day.  Can anybody show me how I could accomplish this?  A sample table could be:

```
MealID      - int NOT NULL PK
ProviderID  - int NOT NULL FK
MealDate    - date NOT NULL
Description - varchar(MAX) NOT NULL
```

And my query thus far is:

```
SELECT *
  FROM MEAL
 WHERE ProviderID = @ProviderID
   AND DATEPART(month, MealDate) = @Month
   AND DATEPART(year, MealDate) = @Year
 ORDER BY MealDate ASC;
```

Comment: Are the Master Menu meals keyed on day of the week; day of the month; or full calendar date?

Comment: On a full calendar date.  The master menu uses the same table to record it's meals.

Comment: The same table, or the same table DDL? If the former, How are the MASTER_MENU meals distinguished from the regular ones?\

Comment: By the foreign key.  There is another table aptly named PROVIDER that has a field indicating if they are the master provider from which all child providers should derive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query needs to be amended something like this:

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(MEAL.Description, MASTER_MENU.Description) as MealDescription,
    -- other fields as required.
  FROM MEAL
  LEFT JOIN MASTER_MENU  on MEAL.MealDate = MASTER_MENU.MealDate
 WHERE ProviderID = @ProviderID
   AND DATEPART(month, MealDate) = @Month
   AND DATEPART(year, MealDate) = @Year
 ORDER BY MealDate ASC;
```

Comment: Neato, I've never needed to use the coalesce keyword. Thanks.

Comment: COALESCE is the ANSI standard which SQL Server formerly only had ISNULL for. COALESCE can take any number of arguments, and will evaluate to the first argument that is NOT NULL.

Comment: Awesome, just the ticket. :)